# Perl installation on Debian vs CentOS

Tags: linux, perl, centos, debian, packages

As described here at http://www.directadmin.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43558&page=1
I am trying to find the equivalent apt-get install commands for the current version of Debian for:

```
 yum install cpan
 yum install perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker
 cpan install ExtUtils::Install
```

These Perl packages don't appear in Debian as you would expect
Thanks

Comment: uh, all of those are part of Perl. You shouldn't have to install anything! Why don't you check if you have them first?

Comment: ikegami: some linux distributions come with perl, but only a very stripped down set of modules.  (Don't know if that's the situation here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most debian packages of perl module distributions are named like libdistro-name-perl.

You can search on http://packages.debian.org (or http://packages.ubuntu.com if you swing that way) for packages that contain files ending with a certain name (e.g. ExtUtils/CBuilder.pm) if necessary.

Comment: HI ysth, I asked a further question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521456/perl-installation-on-debian-vs-centos-with-makefile-pl-error